# xcode resize and position coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode, resize, touch, coordinates

I would like my code (ipad app) to handle resizing of an image by touching it.
I am little confused with how xcode handle points coordinates.
I wrote my code considering that the origin of a frame (frame.origin) is located at the top left (as I read it somewhere), that touches location is the coordinates of the finger touching the screen and that the positive directions are left (x) and up (y). If I am wrong somewhere there that would explain why my code isn't working properly.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGFloat kResizeThumbSize = 45.0f;
    touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat xO = _ImageView.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat yO = _ImageView.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat width = _ImageView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = _ImageView.frame.size.height;
    isResizingUD = (xO - kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.x < xO + width + kResizeThumbSize &&
                (yO - kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.y < yO + kResizeThumbSize ||
                yO - height - kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.y < yO - height + kResizeThumbSize) );
    isResizingLR = (yO + kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.x < xO + width - kResizeThumbSize &&
                (xO - kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.x < xO + kResizeThumbSize ||
                 xO - width - kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.x < xO - width + kResizeThumbSize));
}

//moving the image
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint previous = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self.view];

    CGFloat deltaWidth = touchPoint.x - previous.x;
    CGFloat deltaHeight = touchPoint.y - previous.y;

    // get the frame values so we can calculate changes below
    CGFloat x = _ImageView.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat y = _ImageView.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat width = _ImageView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = _ImageView.frame.size.height;

    if (isResizingLR) {
        _ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width+deltaWidth, height);
    } else if (isResizingUD) {
        _ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height+deltaHeight);
    } else {
        // not dragging from a corner -- move the view
        _ImageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + touchPoint.x - touchStart.x,
                                    self.view.center.y + touchPoint.y - touchStart.y);
    }

}
```

I would expect the image to be resize in the up/down direction only if the user touch the bottom or the top of the image within kResizeThumbSize (which actually, I am not sure of the unit it is expressed in) and in the right/left direction if the user touch the left or right border of the image within kResizeThumbSize. Unfortunately, what's happen is that the image can be resize in the right/left direction only and wherever I put my finger, it will be resized.
Any help would be greatly welcome.

Comment: The UIScrollview class handles zooming automatically. It probably already does what you want; if not, you can always subclass it or use its delegate methods.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I don't understand the link with my question. I am not trying to zoom a view, but to resize an object by increasing the width or the height separately when the user is touching the appropriate border. Moreover, it's an object inserted in the camera view (augmented reality). I definitely don't want a zoom here.

Comment: Oh -- sorry, I misunderstood what you were doing. The coordinate system for UIKit (UIViews, etc.) has its origin in the upper-left. X increases as you move right; Y increases as you move down. I think you have it flipped. You probably read about UIKit vs. CG coordinates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695262/how-to-compensate-the-flipped-coordinate-system-of-core-graphics-for-easy-drawin?rq=1

Comment: Thank you again. I fixed the code and it's now working properly. The fact that the directions were flipped was only one of the issue. It seems a condition such as a < x < b doesn't work. Instead it should be separated as a < x && x < b.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

For anyone needing help for this, I post my code.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGFloat kResizeThumbSize = 10.0f;
    touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat xO = _ImageView.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat yO = _ImageView.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat width = _ImageView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = _ImageView.frame.size.height;
    isResizingUD = (xO - kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.x &&
                touchStart.x < xO + width + kResizeThumbSize &&
                yO + height - kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.y);
    isResizingLR = (yO + kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.y &&
                touchStart.y< yO + height - kResizeThumbSize &&
                xO + width - kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.x);
    isMoving = (xO+kResizeThumbSize< touchStart.x &&
            touchStart.x < xO + width - kResizeThumbSize  &&
            yO + kResizeThumbSize < touchStart.y &&
            touchStart.y< yO + height - kResizeThumbSize);

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint previous = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self.view];

    CGFloat deltaWidth = touchPoint.x - previous.x;
    CGFloat deltaHeight = touchPoint.y - previous.y;

    // get the frame values so we can calculate changes below
    CGFloat x = _ImageView.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat y = _ImageView.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat width = _ImageView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = _ImageView.frame.size.height;

    if (isResizingUD) {
        _ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height+deltaHeight);
    } else if (isResizingLR) {
        _ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width+deltaWidth, height);
    } else if (isMoving) {
        // not dragging from a corner -- move the view
        _ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x+deltaWidth, y+deltaHeight, width, height);
    }

}
```