# Difference between coordinates across the platform on Android and IOS

Tags: android, ipad, mupdf

I am using the MUPDF android library for displaying the PDF on android.

MUPDF returns the PDF as bitmap and I have used the Canvas layer over that to render the annotations such as highlight, underline, strikeout. I am trying to sync the annotations across IPad and Android **it's not working because of coordinates difference in both the devices**. I am using the concept of quadpoints described by adobe for rendering the annotations.

Suppose I am doing Highlight annotations on single line, I am getting top (left and right) and bottom (left and right) `x, y` coordinates.With same coordinates when I am trying to render annotation on iPad, it's not showing anything on screen and vice versa.But when I am trying to sync one android device coordinates with another android device, it renders correctly. Same with one iPad compared to another iPad.

Below is the points for same annotation on same file.

iPad:

```
"quadPoints": [
      [
          "72.06",
          "626.51",
          "390.07",
          "626.51",
          "72.06",
          "610.91",
          "390.07",
          "610.91"
      ]
```

Android:

```
"quadPoints": [
     [
          "57.6",
          "330.96786",
          "312.15",
          "330.96786",
          "57.6",
          "362.2044",
          "312.57",
          "362.2044"
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

CoreGraphics in iOS uses the lower-left point as origin (0,0).

For conversion, see answer: [How to compensate the flipped coordinate system of core graphics for easy drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695262/how-to-compensate-the-flipped-coordinate-system-of-core-graphics-for-easy-drawin)

You can read more in **iOS Drawing Concepts**: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html