# Cannot correctly apply affine transformation to draw a subimage into UIView's context

Tags: ios, uiview, cgcontext, cgaffinetransform, cgimage

I am implementing a subclass of UIView, for which I dynamically call `drawRect(_:)`. To be able to call `drawRect(_:)` only for the updated rect. of the view canvas, I apply my drawing onto a same-sized off-screen image buffer and inside `drawRect(_:)`, I extract the updated subimage and draw into the current context.

The problem I could not fix is that the subimage is drawn as flipped. I know this is normal due to the fact that UIView's origin is at top-left corner and the cropped subimage's origin is at bottom-left corner.

When I flip the subimage before drawing using the following code, no drawing happens. If I remove the lines shown by the arrows, I see the updated subimage as flipped. Can you please show me what is wrong with my affine transformations?

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let _ = bufferImage else { return }

    let scaleFactor = UIScreen.main.scale
    let scaledRect = rect.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor))
    let croppedImage = bufferImage!.cgImage!.cropping(to: scaledRect)!
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)                // <------
    context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -rect.height)    // <------
    context.draw(croppedImage, in: rect)
}
```

Comment: I am going to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13965974/92318). But I still don't understand why my version does not work.

Comment: Can you please try 4 combinations where you swap the translatedBy and scaleBy calls combined with +-rect.height. So `context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0) context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -rect.height)` then `context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0) context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: rect.height)` then `context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -rect.height) context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0) ` and `context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: rect.height) context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)`. Please confirm none of these combinations work.