# Cropping UIImage not yielding expected crop - swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I am trying to crop an image but the crop is not yielding the expected portion of the UIImage.  The images appear out of orientation and mirror-ed.  It is very confusing.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var imgPreViewOutlet: UIImageView!

 guard
        let cgImage = self.imgPreViewOutlet.image.cgImage else {return}


// NORMALISE COORDINATES
let topXn = TOP_LEFT.x/screenWidth
let topYn = TOP_LEFT.y/screenHeight
let widthn = (TOP_RIGHT.x - TOP_LEFT.x)/screenWidth
let heightn = (BOTTOM_RIGHT.y - TOP_RIGHT.y)/screenHeight


// DIMENSION OF CGIMAGE
let cgImgWidth = cgImage.width
let cgImgHeight = cgImage.height

let cropRect = CGRect.init(x: topXn * CGFloat.init(widthn) , y: topYn * CGFloat.init(heightn), width: widthn * CGFloat.init(cgImgWidth), height: heightn * CGFloat.init(cgImgHeight))

if let cgCropImged = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect){

        print("cropRect: \(cropRect)")

        self.imgPreViewOutlet.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgCropImged)
    }
```

[image]

CROPPED:

[image]

Comment: @JonJ makes a good point. Might I add a second one? What specific `CIFilter` are you using? You didn't post it in your code. But based on your images, I *strongly* recommend using `CIPerspectiveCorrection`, not `CICrop` or (as your posted code implies) CoreGraphics.

Comment: I am presently not using any filters, I just want the crop of the rectangle as a first step. but thanks for the tip!

Comment: Since you tagged it as CoreImage, I assumed you did. Your images are *exactly* what CIPerspectiveCorrection can do. This filter takes *any* 4 points - it doesn't need to be a... parallelogram? CGRect?... it's been decades since I learn geometry... and crops everything else. I could post a fairly simple example (Swift 4) if you haven't used any filters before. Let me know. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveCorrection

Comment: @dfd If you could post an example in swift 4 that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, here's an example of using `CIPerspectiveCorrection` to crop your image. I downloaded and used Sketch to get the approximate values of the 4 `CGPoints` in your example image.

```
    let inputBottomLeft = CIVector(x: 38, y: 122)
    let inputTopLeft = CIVector(x: 68, y: 236)
    let inputTopRight = CIVector(x: 146, y: 231)
    let inputBottomRight = CIVector(x: 151, y: 96)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")
    filter?.setValue(inputTopLeft, forKey: "inputTopLeft")
    filter?.setValue(inputTopRight, forKey: "inputTopRight")
    filter?.setValue(inputBottomLeft, forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
    filter?.setValue(inputBottomRight, forKey: "inputBottomRight")

    filter?.setValue(ciOriginal, forKey: "inputImage")
    let ciOutput = filter?.outputImage
```

Please note a few things:

- The most important thing to *never* forget about CoreImage is that the origin of a `CIImage` is *bottom* left, not *top* left. You need to "flip" the Y axis point.
- A `UIImage` has a size, while a `CIImage` has an extent. These are the same. (The only time it isn't is when using a CIFIlter to "create" something - a color, a tiled image - and then it's infinite.)
- A `CIVector` can have quite a few properties. In this case I'm using the X/Y signature, and it's a straight copy of a `CGPoint` except the Y axis is flipped.
- I have a [sample project here](https://github.com/justdfd/CIPerspectiveCorrection) that uses a `UIImageView`. Be aware that performance on the simulator is nowhere near what performance is on a real device - I recommend using a device anytime CoreImage is involved. Also, I did a straight translation from the output CIImage to a UIImage. It usually better to use a `CIContext` and `CoreGraphics` if you are looking for performance.

Given your input, here's the output:

[image]

Comment: This solution is perfect as i have been trying to crop a quadrilateral.  I was going in a very roundabout and intensive direction. many thanks!

Comment: one question though. when you say 'flip' the y axis.  So if I have a CGPoint(x: 60, y: 60) what does this translate to upon flipping?

Comment: Hmph. Quadrilateral - my description came close. Anyways - flipping the Y axis. The image I used was 180 width by 320 height. Let's say you have a CGPoint (in this case, inputBottomLeft) of X == 38 and Y == 188. Keep the X value but "flip" the Y by taking the height (310) and subtracting the UIImage Y value (188). 310 - 188 = 122. Some time ago I had a simple function to do this but I couldn't find it easily. If you followed *my* example here, then you know that `CGPoint(x:60, y:60)` translates to... well, X is 60... but Y depends on the `maxY` or `CGRect.height` value.

Comment: I added a follow up to this question if you could advise, based on your above solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374579/unable-to-display-image-after-using-cifilter-swift

Comment: I downloaded your sample project, but unfortunately it was empty.

Comment: Doh! I forgot to commit/push it. It's there now.

Answer (score 3):

Core graphics coordinates are from an origin point at the bottom left, UIKit coordinates are from top left. I think you're confusing the two.

This might help:

[How to compensate the flipped coordinate system of core graphics for easy drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695262/how-to-compensate-the-flipped-coordinate-system-of-core-graphics-for-easy-drawin)